# Their names, the names of them

Tags: possessives

Is the construction "the names of them" used in the sense "their names" totally ungrammatical? Is it acceptable in dialects?

Comment: You can use ngram viewer to check.

Comment: John Locke uses "the names of them", but the guy buying a burger at the football game will say "their names". https://books.google.com/books?id=jg7BtAow1y0C&pg=PT312&dq=%22the+names+of+them%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF5IWY6qnWAhWGWCYKHXHnDjoQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22the%20names%20of%20them%22&f=false    *I used to know all of the atomic weights of the elements, but now I can barely remember the names of them.*  Both are viable.  *their names* is used far more often.   "the names of them" emphasizes *names*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The names of them" is certainly *grammatical*, just somewhat more awkward than "their names".

> I met so many people at the party, I can't remember **the names of them** all.
>   I met so many people at the party, I can't remember all **their names**.

As with many things in English, the order of words can change the emphasis.  Without any additional inflection, the first sentence slightly emphasizes *names*, while the second slightly emphasizes *their*.

Because it's difficult to fit into a sentence, I would avoid using "the names of them" unless I had a really good reason.